# Select Download File from One of Two Select Boxes with One Button - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, html-select

I have two `select` boxes like so:

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="default">Select File</option>
    <option value="path/to/file1">File One</option>
    <option value="path/to/file2">File Two</option>
    <option value="path/to/file3">File Three</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
    <option value="default">Select File</option>
    <option value="path/to/file4">File Four</option>
    <option value="path/to/file5">File Five</option>
    <option value="path/to/file6">File Six</option>
</select>

<p class="button_image">
    <a onclick="download(document.getElementById("one").value)"></a>
</p>
```

Here is my `download` function:

```
function download(file) {
    if (file == 'default') return;
    window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/download/' + file;
}
```

This works fine for one `select` box, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the same button image.  Oh yah, the `p.class=button_image` has background image that is a button with hover effects.

The reason I want these `select` boxes to be separate is because they each represent a group of files, eg, 32-bit versus 64-bit.  So they cannot be combined, because it won't flow with the page design.

I've tried some if/else blocks in PHP using the `getElementById` but I'm getting stuck.  This is what I tried and it seems to only partially work:

```
<?php

if ('document.getElementById(\"one\")' == 'one') {
    echo "<a onclick='download(document.getElementById(\"one\").value)'></a>";
}

else if ('document.getElementById(\"two\")' == 'two') {
    echo "<a onclick='download(document.getElementById(\"one\").value)'></a>";
}

?>
```

I should note that I don't necessarily need to use PHP in this case to solve this problem.  It was just an option I tried because I'm using PHP for the server-side programming.  I could be happy with any number of options, so long as they work.

Thanks.

** EDIT **

This design might be flawed.  But the intention is that either a file from box one is downloaded OR a file from box two is downloaded.  If one selection is made, then the other should be rest to `default` and vice versa.  This is what I'm working on now.

** EDIT **

I ended up goign with Dawson Loudon's answer for one part and I created another function based on Barmar's comment that looks like this:

```
// resets other select box when selected
function reset_index(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex = 'default';
}
```

Comment: What should happen if they select a file from both `select` boxes before clicking the button?

Comment: Yah, I'm sorry for not adding that.  I'm realizing that this design has flaws.  Ideally, if one is chosen, then the other is reset to default.  There is no option for both being selected.  Either a file from one box or the other is how it's meant to be.

Comment: Consider either using one select or radio buttons (my preference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
<p class="button_image">
    <a onclick="download(document.getElementById('one').value)"></a>
</p>
```

with:

```
<p class="button_image">
    <a onclick="download(document.getElementById('one').value, document.getElementById('two').value)"></a>
</p>
```

and then replace your download function with this:

```
function download(file1,file2) {
    if (file1 == 'default' && file2 == 'default'){
      return;
    }
    else if(file1 != 'default'){
      window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/download/' + file1;
    }
    else{
      window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/download/' + file2;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this works better, but I'm still running into the first one taking precedence over the second.  For example, if the first one is chosen then it will win out.  I will need to figure out how to reset the other select box, when one is chosen.

Comment: Use an `onchange` handler in each that resets the other.

Answer (score 2):

An A element as a button doesn't seem appropriate, just use an img.

Anyhow, a function to use the first select with a selected option other than the first can be something like:

```
function getPath() {
  var select;
  var args = arguments;

  for (var i=0, iLen=args.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    select = document.getElementById(arg[i]);

    if (select && select.selectedIndex > 0) {
      window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/download/' + select.value;
    } 
  } 
}
```

The above expects the first option to be the default selected, so if it's selected, or no option at all is selected, the select's selectedIndex will be 0 or -1 respsectively. I would ensure one option is selected by adding the selected attribute to the first one:

```
  <option value="default" selected>Select File</option>
```

and the call is:

```
<img src="buttonImage.jpg" onclick="download('one', 'two');">
```

though you might want to add a class to the select elements and get them using getElementsByClassName or similar and loop over that collection, rather than hard code the ids.

Comment: I agree on the `a` tag, I think that was vestigial from another method.  I will probably change that - thanks.